# Add click on every child one by one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a slider which has no auto scroll, so I need a jquery function to add auto scroll on the slider. these are the slider indicator, which changes the slides.

```
<div class="slider__navi">
<a href="#" class="slide-nav" data-slide="1">pikachu</a>
<a href="#" class="slide-nav" data-slide="2">piplup</a>
<a href="#" class="slide-nav" data-slide="3">blaziken</a>
<a href="#" class="slide-nav active" data-slide="4">dialga</a>
</div>
```

I am doing it with `setInterval` like:

```
setInterval(function(){
for (var i = 1 ; i <= 4; i++) {
$('.slide-nav:nth-child(' + i +')').click();
} 
},1000)
```

but it is not right, I want to click each slide-nav one by one, or add active class one by one by waiting some time.

Comment: Please show your full code

Comment: Your current code sets an interval timer that, when it runs, does **all four**. You want each timer to do just one, so you don't use a `for` loop. Instead, you have the timer function close over the index variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $(function(){
      $('.slide-nav').click(function(){
          $('.active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
      });
      let currentLink = 1;
      let linkLengths = $('.slide-nav').length;
      setInterval(function(){
          $('.slide-nav:nth-child(' + currentLink++ +')').click();
          if(currentLink == linkLengths+1 ){
              currentLink = 1;
          }
      }, 1000)
});
```

This should do it. https://jsfiddle.net/msvqyhrd/

Answer (score 0):

when you select all `.slide-nav` then **click** event bind on each item of list one by one

the interval is wrong way

use this instead:

```
    $('.slider__navi').on('click', '.slide-nav', function(){
        var target = $(this).data("slide");
        //do stuff to scroll

        // set active class
        $('.slide-nav').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // see target
        console.log(target)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
slideShow();

function slideShow() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-nav");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(slideShow, 1000); // Change image every 1 seconds
}
</script>
```